# Load more than one URL in UIWebView one by one

Tags: iphone, ios, webview

Hi! I am developing an application. In that I am creating one webview. By using that webview I want to load the next url after completion of first one. I written the `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` like this

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
   {
      [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        alert_View=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"\n\nData sent successfully!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert_View show];
        [alert_View release];
      [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeAlert:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
   }
```

And the removeAlert method looks like

```
  -(void)removeAlert:(id)sender
  {
     [alert_View dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
    [web loadRequest:[arr objectAtIndex:1];
  }
```

`arr` array contain all prepared requests. When ever this `removeAlert` method executed directly `-(void)webView:didFailLoadWithError:` method is fired. So please tell me how can I load another request after end of first one?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ARC, you should get rid of the `[alert_View release]`. The alert view may not be retained, and that could be contributing to the problem.

Also, try `[self performSelector: @selector(removeAlert:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];` and see if that works, instead of your `NSTimer` call.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by delegating. So once your first request is processed and you get a response, you can send the next one.

If you arent familiar with delegates, here's a [link](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/) to get you started.